# Temp folders getting created on C:\ Drive

Tags: windows-10, temporary-files

Every days there is X numbers of empty temp folders getting created on my C:\ drive.

[image: Empty temp folders]

Deleting them manually doesn't help because they keep getting created.

How can I find out which app is creating them?

Comment: They are being created by Adobe CC. See [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2180330)

Answer (score 2):

The folders are made by Adobe CC, a Google search for "TEMPzxpsign" showed others who have reported similar folders. There doesn't seem to be a fix for it at the moment. The folders themselves are empty and therefore harmless. Deleting them doesn't seem to affect the program in any way.

Maybe you can even consider creating a script that clears the folder every time you close an Adobe program.